# Display webpage with unix domain socket

Tags: chrome, tcp, http, browser, unix-sockets

Is there a way to serve a webpage from a locally running tcp server listening on a unix domain socket instead of `localhost:<port>`?

something like:

```
file:///tmp/webpage.sock
```

my only real motivation is to avoid port conflicts in the 2000-5000 range.

Comment: The WHATWG seems to discuss this currently: https://github.com/whatwg/url/issues/577

Comment: Seems to be a similar question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771172/http-over-af-unix-http-connection-to-unix-socket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes

It is easy to serve it.

## No

But harder to get the client to use it.

## An alternative

However because you told me why you are doing it, I have another solution.

You want several web-servers to serve to only the local machine, but not have conflicts of port. It may also be nice if they all used the same port number.

Loopback addresses are `127.0.0.0/8` That is `127.x.x.x` not just `127.0.0.1`.

Therefore use a different IP address for each server. E.g. `127.0.0.2`, `127.0.0.3` ...

Comment: cool, I can try the other loopback addresses. Could you add an example of using unix sockets as well? just curious how it would work.

Comment: I don't know if the servers are programmed to do it. But you could listen on a high port, and use port forwarding. I just went for multiple loop-back addresses.

Comment: yeah the multiple loop back addresses is cool. will prob use that. but I am really curious how it could be done with unix domain sockets, any idea how?

Comment: I would look at netcat. It may be able to forward it. `ssh` can do it but there is overhead of encryption.  Both would need the server to listen on a socket, and would just forward from another unix socket. I think I did it once. But could not convince the browser to use it. I would ask another question. But **be clear about what you are not asking for**, and link to this question.

Comment: yeah but netcat would be listening on a port and then forwarding to the unix domain socket? ultimately I am trying to avoid listening on a port at all, so that defeats the purpose, but your original idea to use a different loopback address is good.